# How to acces EditText value from AlertDialog Builder from another layout?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, layout-inflater

I have this code in my Config activity and the dialog is activated when i press a add_count TextView, my problem seems to be that the value i get on get_cont is null, maybe because the inflater doesn't work right ?
(usernames and passwords are ArrayLists)

```
add_cont.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

         AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Config.this);
         LayoutInflater inflater = Config.this.getLayoutInflater();
         final View dialog_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_cont, null);
         builder.setTitle("Add cont.");
         builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_cont, null))
         .setPositiveButton(R.string.create_cont, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   EditText get_cont = (EditText)dialog_layout.findViewById(R.id.username);
                   EditText get_pass = (EditText)dialog_layout.findViewById(R.id.password);

                   String test_cont = get_cont.getText().toString();
                   String text_pass = getpass.getText().toString();

                   usernames.add(3, get_cont.getText().toString());
                   passwords.add(3, get_pass.getText().toString());
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel_cont, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                  dialog.cancel();
               }
           }); 
         AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
         alertDialog.show();

    }
});
```

and my dialog_add_cont layout looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:hint="username" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:hint="password"/>
```

Did i got the code somewhere wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inflating dialog_layout and never using it since you are inflating the xml again and setting it directly for the dialog.

your code should be like this:

```
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Config.this);
  LayoutInflater inflater = Configurare.this.getLayoutInflater();
  final View dialog_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_cont, null);
  builder.setTitle("Add cont.");
  builder.setView(dialog_layout)
....
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing this?

```
@Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               Dialog d = (Dialog) dialog;
               EditText get_cont = (EditText)d.findViewById(R.id.username);
               EditText get_pass = (EditText)d.findViewById(R.id.password);

               String test_cont = get_cont.getText().toString();
               String text_pass = get_cont.getText().toString();

               usernames.add(3, get_cont.getText().toString());
               passwords.add(3, get_pass.getText().toString());
           }
```

Comment: Yes, but still gets null.

Comment: Hei, i also tested the new code and it's working. :D

Comment: I am glad it worked but you didn't accept it as the answer. I wonder why. :P

Comment: Well after i wrote you that it didn't worked i tried the @Mr.Me code and it did fine. So it was a timing thing :D.